# Proof that any antisymmetric matrix C is congruent to a block diagonal matrix?

Tags: jordan-normal-form, symmetric-matrices, matrix-congruences

Is there a simple proof that shows that, for any antisymmetric $C$, there exists an orthogonal matrix $P$ such that $P^TCP$ is a block diagonal matrix?

I have found a couple of very longwinded proofs but I feel there must be shorter ones out there.

Edit: Block = $2 \times 2$

Comment: Isn't any square matrix technically already block diagonal with one large block? So $P = I$ should work.

Comment: Sorry, I mean 2x2 blocks